# How to save changes in emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

I tried to load a game on an android emulator. When I close the emulator and open it again the game is still there but, it doesn't save—always starting from the first stage. Is there a way to save changes on the emulator?

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: The emulator should work like a normal physical device. There is no need for special treatment on any app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The emulator has its own portion of disk dedicated to its 'internal memory', so your settings and information should be saved.

Perhaps the game saves information on the SD card, in which case the emulator may not be configured to allow saving on a virtual memory card.

Create a new virtual device and set it up with a virtual SD card, and see if that helps.

See here for more information on virtual devices:

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/index.html

Answer (score 0):

To add to the HXCaine, if you want to create sd card, you can make use of the "mksdcard.exe" present in the tools directory of the Android SDK.

When creating the emulator there select the file which is created through the mksdcard.exe file.

For selecting for the already created Emulator, In Eclipse go to
Window->Android SDK & AVD Manager -> Select the AVD -> Edit -> SDCard section select the File radio button and then browse to the file which is created through mksdcard.exe

Save the changes and restart the emulator.

Regards,
SSuman185